# Карта лояльности клиента

Tags: семантика

Я - владелец сети кофеен. Хочу выпустить бонусную карту (10-й напиток бесплатно). Корректно ли будет назвать карту "карта лояльности клиента"? Или это все-таки банковский термин/крупной торговой сети и т.д.?

Answer (score 5):

Это не противоречит сложившейся практике - я встречал даже в распечатках чеков "скидка по карте лояльности". Но это не самый привлекательный рекламный приём (у посетителя не должно откладываться в подсознании, что его с расчётливым цинизмом привязывают к конкретному заведению, экономически склоняя к **постоянству выбора** - в данном случае смысл **лояльности** именно этот), хотя во внутренних документах вполне можно эту карту так называть. Нежелательно, чтобы это наименование в каких-то случаях (в меню, на чеке) попадалось на глаза клиенту. Для клиента привлекательнее "карта скидок (дисконтная карта)" или "бонусная карта" - он должен замечать свою выгоду, а не чужую.

Answer (score 3):

Знаете, на такие вещи нормативов нету. Как хотите, так и называйте. Чем глупее - тем рекламнее. Тем более, что до Вас это сто раз сделали, а никаких причин разделять точки обслуживания на крупные и мелкие или там на супермаркеты и кофейни применительно к использованию таких терминов я не вижу.

Вообще термин "лояльность" - не самый удачный применительно именно к клиентам. Он переводной и в оригинале имеет куда более широкое значение. А в русском английское loyalty соответствует трем разным словам: верность, преданность и лояльность. В нашем случае правильным переводом была бы "верность". Но - не сложилось, появилась эта "лояльность". Так что пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

"Лояльность" звучит как калька с английского. Может быть, ограничиться старой доброй картой постоянного покупателя?

Comment: Да это понятно, что с английского, только во-первых, не калька, а скорее ЛДП, во-вторых, не все, что с английского, что плохо.  Но самое главное, вопрос-то не в этом. Интересует, насколько понял, не "как лучше",  а именно корректность выбранного.

Answer (score 0):

> Потребительская лояльность, лояльность к бренду — приверженность покупателей к торговой марке, мотивированная прочно укоренившейся привычкой покупать одно и то же изделие, товар или пользоваться одной и той же услугой, a также невосприимчивость к цене товара, отвержение альтернативы. (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Таким образом, при упоминании о лояльности у меня в подсознании загорается красная лампочка: это торговое заведения действует, мягко говоря, не в моих интересах.